# In a single page desktop-like application, should I dynamically instanciate a controller for a window? How?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I'm asking this because I really don't know **where** I should handle events of my dynamically created window.

When someone clicks on a desktop icon, the window (if it doesn't exist) will be dynamically created. Should I create a controller when creating the window and hook to it? If yes, how?

Here you can read different approaches I've thought about:

1. Create a controller that will instanciate the Window (as its view), I will handle everything there
2. Create the window only and hook everything in my taskbar controller (which is where the window is created). In this case, the Taskbar controller will become very big.
3. Pre-create all window controllers and eventually windows too and hide them (when page is ready). Then just show/hide them, so I will have "static" references to all controllers with getController in Application

Which approach should I use?

**Edit 1:**
I'm trying to dynamically instanciate (and reference it through another controller) a controller. I'm having hard time expecially in referencing it. Any suggestion on how it should be done?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET as a backend, you should take a look at [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase/).

Comment: No sorry, I'm using Ruby on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself: I preinstanciate the controller as I do with all controllers, by inserting them in Application controllers array. After this, I instanciate the view on that controller when a method is called, then I simply use refs to access this view.

The method is quite clean and using refs feel so good. Obviusly the controller has a method hasWindow which checks if the controller view has been created already.

Comment: you beat me too it, but that is the right approach. please see the Secnha guides to MVC they are quite good. First of 3 parts: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/mvc_pt1

Comment: I already read them (all 3 plus the "getting started"), maybe I missed it because I read them quite fast. However I like this approach, I'm liking extJS, quite satisfact and it doesn't cost **so much** (well, it costs :P ).

Answer (score 0):

I found Ext's MVC unusable with desktop demo as it's possible to have multiple windows (views) of the same type tied to a single controller. Each window has it's own state and it's hard to differentiate between the views in the controller.

Comment: I think it's possible, it's just hard to think about the approach, but it's not impossible.